# WSDL JAVA w3.org premature end of file

Tags: java, soap, service, soapui, soap-client

[ERROR] Premature end of file.
row 1 di http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime

[ERROR] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
row 1 di https://*********************************-soap/soap02?wsdl

my application has been reporting this error for a while when I call the SOAP WSDL. The service is reachable but it seems that the w3c schema is not read in https.

Has anyone had the same problem?

I tried to generate the client via soapUI but still the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it would be enough to run the command that generates the client on a wsdl that has the header of the wsdl w3c in http :

wsimport -keep https://****************************************/soap02?wsdl

Comment: [SOLVED] The problem reported is related to the java library jaxws-api-2.3.1 that inside the javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding interface there are URLs to the W3 schemes in http and do not follow the automatic https redirect.
The solution is here: 
https://blog.saverioriotto.it/forum/4/error-orgxmlsaxsaxparseexception-systemid-httpwwww3org200505xmlmime-premature-end-of-file